# Question Pertaining to Equivalent Resistance

Tags: resistors

I've got another question which pertains to Thevenins and Nortons Theorem. This time is about disabling all independent sources to find the Rn or Rth. I have the circuit attached below, and once disabling the independent sources I can't tell which resistors are in parallel or in series. I've also attached an attempt of mine where I coloured all the nodes to try and visualize which are in series or parallel but It was incorrect, on the right side is a redrawn circuit with the 8kOhm and 1kOhm in series and other notes. Is there a good way of thinking about this or a rule which makes visualizing which resistors are in parallel or series easier?

Thank you.

[image: The given circuit.]

[image: My attempt at finding equivalent resistance.]

Comment: Two resistors are in parallel if their ends are tied to the same nodes. In your diagram `8k` and `1k` have their ends connected together. One end of each is connected red node. The other end of each is connected to the green node. So they're in parallel.

Comment: `1k` and `9k` are NOT in series because their meeting is not unique. Another branch is going of that node to the shorted voltage source.

Comment: So 8K and and 1K are then in parallel because their two end nodes are the same. Does this mean moving further, the 8||1 is in series with the 5K resistor which is parallel to the 9K resistor?

Comment: Yes, the best way to tell if two resistors are in series is to check that same current flows through both.

Comment: Similarly when two resistors are in parallel, same voltage appears across both.